# hana::make_map with lifted template

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-hana

I'm trying to create a map of Key-Task pairs at compilation time. The key is a sequential number which should also be used as a template parameter inside of the mapped Task types. What I learned is that I need to lift my Task into a metafunction to make that work but I'am already getting problems in creating the right `hana::types` that match my template parameters.

This is what I have so far:

```
template <std::size_t Key,
          typename T = double,
          template<typename...> class Complex = std::complex>
class Task
{
    ...
}

template <std::size_t Begin,
          std::size_t End,
          typename T,
          template<typename...> class Complex = std::complex>
class TaskFactory
{
    static constexpr auto create(void)
    {
        auto keys = hana::make_range(hana::int_c<Begin>, hana::int_c<End>);

        return hana::unpack(keys, [](auto... key)
        {
            return hana::make_map(hana::make_pair(key, hana::template_<Task>(hana::type_c<key>, hana::type_c<T>, hana::type_c<Complex>)())...);
        });
    }

    static constexpr auto taskMap_ = create();

    ...
}

int main()
{
    TaskFactory<2, 8, double, std::complex> myTaskFactory;
    return 0;
}
```

Clang is complaining with:

> error: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter

What am I doing wrong and is this the right approach?

Best
Wum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hana::template_` only works with `typename` template parameters - it doesn't support *non-type template parameters* or *template template parameters*. See [its implementation here](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/cae3fb3fb3f3f1d88a89fe88c3f15e6261a4fd3e/include/boost/hana/type.hpp#L152-L165).

The same applies for `hana::type_c`.

- `hana::type_c<key>` is not valid as `key` is not a type.
- `hana::type_c<Complex>` is not valid as `Complex` is not a type.

Your approach up to `hana::unpack(keys, [](auto... key)` looks OK to me. You need to change your `Task` class to be defined in terms of types - e.g.:

```
template <typename Key,
          typename Complex>
class Task
{
    // ...
};
```

That way, you can use `hana::template_` as you intend to.

Comment: Should have seen this! Thanks Vittorio.